# Awkward JOIN causes poor performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-execution-plan

I have a stored procedure that combines data from several tables via `UNION ALL`. If the parameters passed in to the stored procedure don't apply to a particular table, I attempt to "short-circuit" that table by using "helper bits", e.g. `@DataSomeTableExists` and adding a corresponding condition in the `WHERE` clause, e.g. `WHERE @DataSomeTableExists = 1`

One (psuedo) table in the stored procedure is a bit awkward and causing me some grief.

```
DECLARE @DataSomeTableExists BIT = (SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #T WHERE StorageTable = 'DATA_SomeTable') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
...  

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM REF_MinuteDimension AS dim WITH (NOLOCK)  
CROSS JOIN  (SELECT * FROM #T WHERE StorageTable = 'DATA_SomeTable') AS T       
CROSS APPLY dbo.fGetLastValueFromSomeTable(T.ParentId, dim.TimeStamp) dpp
WHERE @DataSomeTableExists = 1 AND dim.TimeStamp >= @StartDateTime AND dim.TimeStamp <= @EndDateTime

UNION ALL

...
```

Note: `REF_MinuteDimension` is nothing more than smalldatetimes with minute increments.

(1) The execution plan (below) indicates a warning on the nested loops operator saying that there is no join predicate. This is probably not good, but there really isn't a natural join between the tables. Is there a better way to write such a query? For each ParentId in T, I want the value from the UDF for every minute between @StartDateTime and @EndDateTime.

(2) Even when `@DataSomeTableExists = 0`, there is I/O activity on the tables in this query as reported by `SET STATISTICS IO ON` and the actual execution plan. The execution plan reports 14.2 % cost which is too much considering these tables don't even apply in this case.

`SELECT * FROM #T WHERE StorageTable = 'DATA_SomeTable'` comes back empty.

Is it the way my query is written? Why wouldn't the helper bit or an empty T short circuit this query?

[image]

Comment: You should change that `DECLARE` thing to this: `declare @DataSomeTableExists bit = 0
if exists(SELECT * FROM #T WHERE StorageTable = 'DATA_SomeTable')
begin
 set @DataSomeTableExists = 1
end`.  That's hard to read, so here's [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/4y0VTJCD).  And why don't you have your "short circuit" `WHERE` argument in the `CROSS JOIN` query also?  I should mention, I have *no clue* if this will ever work, as it's kind of an odd way to write a sproc.

Answer (score 0):

For 2) I can sure say that line

```
CROSS JOIN  (SELECT * FROM #T WHERE StorageTable = 'DATA_SomeTable') AS T
```

Ill force #T to be analysed and to enter a join. You can create to versions of a SP with and without that join and use that flag to execute one or another but I cannot say that ill save any response time||cpu clocks||I/O bandwith||memory.

For 1) I suggest to remove the (nolock) if you are using SQL Server 2005 or better and to keep a close eye in that UDF. Cannot say more without a good SQL fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I should mention, I have *no clue* if this will ever work, as it's kind of an odd way to write a sproc and table-valued UDFs aren't well understood by the query optimizer.  You might have to build your resultset into a table variable or temp table conditionally, based on `IF` statements, then return that data.  But I would try this, first:

```
--helper bit declared
declare @DataSomeTableExists BIT = 0x0
if exists (select 1 from #T where StorageTable = 'DATA_SomeTable')
begin
    set @DataSomeTableExists = 0x1
end

...  

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM REF_MinuteDimension AS dim WITH (NOLOCK)  
CROSS JOIN  (SELECT * FROM #T WHERE StorageTable = 'DATA_SomeTable' and @DataSomeTableExists = 0x1) AS T
CROSS APPLY dbo.fGetLastValueFromSomeTable(T.ParentId, dim.TimeStamp) dpp
WHERE @DataSomeTableExists = 0x1 AND dim.TimeStamp >= @StartDateTime AND dim.TimeStamp <= @EndDateTime

UNION ALL

...
```

And if you don't know already, the UDF might be giving you weird readings in the execution plans.  I don't know enough to give you accurate data, but you should search around to understand the limitations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That seems to do the trick. Curious why you changed the helper bit declaration? Is this just for readability?

Comment: Yeah.  You're declaring a variable, setting it's default value, while also querying using `EXISTS` with a subquery `SELECT`.  That's a lot for the next developer to sit down and read when there are other ways to easily write it.

Answer (score -1):

Since your query is dependent on run-time variables, consider using **dynamic SQL** to create your query on the fly.  This way you can include the tables you want and exclude the ones you don't want.

There are downsides to dynamic SQL, so [read up](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e697a3d6-8811-463d-8624-6c9ec370a8eb/dynamic-sql-pros-cons?forum=transactsql)

Comment: A better alternative, as @jean has suggested, is to create one stored procedure each for when the data needs to be pulled and when the data does not.  Then, from a master sproc, conditionally fire one sproc or the other.  Then you are using *dynamic logic* (and retaining query plans) but not *dynamic SQL* (which is almost never really required, so should be avoided).